# AppleScript mouse commands in a background user

Tags: applescript, mouse, user-account

We use AppleScript (Javascript to be precise) to automate certain UI tests. The script uses the mouse (using MouseTools) and the keyboard (using `system.keystroke` and `system.keyCode`). This has been working well for months.

Now we would like to run the script simultaneously for several users, to increase parallelity:

- Multiple local macOS users are logged in simultaneously.
- Every user runs the same script, and each of these script "instances" runs the UI tests (for example, on different versions of the same app).

However, this does not work 100%. As soon as one user is "in the background", some mouse commands fail or are not placed correctly. It seems that as soon as you click "Lock Screen" and then "Switch User", the current user gets placed in some kind of background state, in which the mouse commands either fail, or in which the screen size is changed in some way that currently prevents our tests to succeed. Keyboard commands seem to work fine.

How can we deal with this? What kind of "screen" or mouse coordinates are available to users that are logged in, but not in the foreground?